# Getting garbage instead of variable when passing through functions

Tags: c, scanf

So this is probably an easy fix, but I can't seem to figure it out.

> User enters `N` to enter a number. 
>   Then the user enters F to print the Fibonacci sequence to that number.

My original print 0-20 (working code) is commented out. I tried setting up the Fibonacci the same way, but get garbage when printing the number. I have it set up now to where it pauses before the for loop so I can see what number it's getting.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char menu();
int read_int(int number);
void display(int answer);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int number = 0;     
    char choice = 'O';
    while (choice != 'X'){
        choice = menu();    

        if (choice != 'N' && choice != 'F' && choice != 'X') {
            printf("Invalid Input. Enter N, F, or X\n");
        }

        else if (choice == 'N') {
            number = read_int(number);
            printf("\nNumber equals: ");
            printf("%d", number);           
        }

        else if (choice == 'F') {
            //printf("\nNumber equals: ");
            //printf("%d", number);         
            display(number);            
        }
    }
}


char menu () 
{
    char i; 
    printf("\nEnter N to enter an integer from 0 to 20\nEnter F to display the first N+1 numbers (beginning with zero) on the console \nEnter X to quit the program \n");

    printf("Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%s",  &i);
    return i;
}   

int read_int(int number)
{
    number = 0;
    printf("\nEnter an integer 0-20: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number >=0 && number <=20)
        return number;
    else{
        printf("Enter a valid number between 0 and 20");    
        return read_int(number);
    }
}

void display(int answer)
{
//  int count = 0;
//  //printf("\nNumber equals: ");
//  //printf("%d", answer); 
//  //int toprint = answer;
//  while (count <= answer){            
//      printf("%d",count);
//      printf(" , ");
//      count=count+1;
   //int n = answer;
   int n = 0;
   n = answer;
   int first = 0, second = 1, next, c;

   //printf("Enter the number of terms\n");


   printf("\nNumber equals: ");
   printf("%d", &answer);
   scanf("%d",&n);
   for ( c = 0 ; c < answer ; c++ )
   {
      if ( c <= 1 )
         next = c;
      else
      {
         next = first + second;
         first = second;
         second = next;
      }
      printf("%d\n",next);
   } 

   //return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d", &answer);` looks suspicius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, the problem is created from

```
 scanf("%s",  &i);
```

`%s` expects a pointer to a `char` array, not a single `char` element. Even for a single `char` input, this will create memory overrun which leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can replace that with

```
 scanf(" %c", &i);
```

Also, `printf("%d", &answer);` looks wrong, I think you don't mean that `&` to be there.

Comment: I added the & trying to get it to work. Changing it to %c and removing the & did solve that problem, but caused another. I can fix it though. Knew it was something simple, just couldn't figure it out!